# Not working Class-Path reference

Tags: deployment, jboss, weblogic

I have this error when deploy war with wlfullclient.jar on the jboss:

```
erver:server-one] 17:27:12,937 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015960: Class Path entry lib\jcom.jar in /C:/Users/admin/Desktop/JBoss/EAP/content/ek-web-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/wlfull3client-10.3.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
erver:server-one] 17:27:12,957 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015960: Class Path entry lib\weblogic-L10N.jar in /C:/Users/admin/Desktop/JBoss/EAP/content/ek-web-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/wlfull3client-10.3.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
erver:server-one] 17:27:13,747 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
erver:server-one] 17:27:13,748 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
erver:server-one] 17:27:13,749 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
erver:server-one] 17:27:16,584 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class weblogic.wsee.jaxws.client.async.AsyncTransportProvider in Module "deployment.ek-web-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link weblogic/wsee/jaxws/client/async/AsyncTransportProvider (Module "deployment.ek-web-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:527)
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
erver:server-one]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
erver:server-one]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
erver:server-one]     at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116)
```

My MANIFEST.FM in the wlfullclient.jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle Corp.
Implementation-Title: JDK 1.6 Client jar for WebLogic Server 10.3  Fri
  Apr 9 00:05:28 PDT 2010 1321401 
Implementation-Version: 10.3.3.0
Class-Path: lib\weblogic-container-binding.jar lib\weblogic-doma
 in-binding.jar lib\diagnostics-binding.jar lib\diagnostics-imag
 e-binding.jar lib\kodo-conf-binding.jar lib\wlcipher.jar lib\x
 mlx.jar lib\ojdbc6.jar lib\EccpressoAsn1.jar lib\EccpressoCore
 .jar lib\EccpressoJcae.jar lib\mysql-connector-java-commercial-
 5.0.3-bin.jar  lib\wlbase.jar lib\wlutil.jar lib\wlsqlser lib
 \ver.jar lib\wldb2.jar lib\wlsybase.jar lib\wlinf lib\ormix.j
 ar lib\wlw-langx.jar lib\pdev.jar lib\jcom.jar lib\web
 logic-L10N.jar
```

Anyone know what path should be in this file? 
(I`ve jars in the lib direcotry in the jar).

Comment: path should be what you have in the .war. What is the contents of your .war?

Answer (score 0):

weblogic/wsee/jaxws/client/async/AsyncTransportProvider is in weblogic.jar, I don't see you including that